# Program crashes when SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail is called

Tags: c++, device, hid, wdk

I'm trying to get the path of a device by using the SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() function, but it crashes everytime I call it. I've have been working on this for over 12 hours but still couldn't find out what is wrong with it... Can someone see if they can find what is actually causing this to happen? Heres the code:

```
//DeviceManager.h
#include <windows.h>
//#include <hidsdi.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <devpkey.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"{
    #include <hidsdi.h>
}

//#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

class DeviceManager
{
public:
    DeviceManager();
    ~DeviceManager();

    void ListAllDevices();
    void GetDeviceHandler();

    //HANDLE PSMove;
    //byte reportBuffer[57];
    GUID guid;
//private:
    HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet;             //A list of all the devices
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;     //A device from deviceInfoSet

    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailedData;
};

//DeviceManager.cpp
#include"DeviceManager.h"

DeviceManager::DeviceManager()
{
    //deviceInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA;
    //deviceInterfaceDetailedData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA;

    HidD_GetHidGuid(&guid);
    deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE); //Gets all Devices
    GetDeviceHandler();
}

DeviceManager::~DeviceManager()
{
}

void DeviceManager::ListAllDevices()
{
    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;

    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
    {
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

        ULONG tcharSize;
        CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(&tcharSize, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);
        TCHAR* deviceIDBuffer = new TCHAR[tcharSize];   //the device ID will be stored in this array, so the tcharSize needs to be big enough to hold all the info.
                                                        //Or we can use MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, which is 200
        CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceIDBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0); //gets the devices ID - a long string that looks like a file path.

        std::cout << deviceIDBuffer << std::endl;

        deviceIndex++;
    }
}

void DeviceManager::GetDeviceHandler()
{
     DWORD deviceIndex = 0;

SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailedData;

deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
{
    TCHAR deviceID[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];

    CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceID, MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, 0);

    //std::cout << deviceID << std::endl;

    deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    if(SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfoData, &guid, 0, &deviceInterfaceData))
    {
        DWORD bufferLength = 0;
        //deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = 2048;
        //std::cout << "it works not" << std::endl;

        if(SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &bufferLength, NULL))
        {
            //deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(bufferLength);
            std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }


    deviceIndex++;
}

}

//mainapp.cpp
#pragma once

int main()
{
DeviceManager deviceManager;

return 0;
}
```

The SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail function is called in the GetDeviceHandler() function of DeviceManager.

Please help. Thanks.

UPDATE: I have found out that it failed on the first SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail and is returning a 122 error (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER). But I am only trying to get the required buffer size, so how can this be??

UPDATE 2: right, I have changed the function a bit (see above code) by setting the deviceInterfaceData.cbsize to 2048 (a huge space for testing purposes) and now I'm getting a ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. This is getting more and more confusing... How can the parameters I've given is invalid? Just doesn't make sense. The only difference is I passed in References instead of Pointers because otherwise I will get a access violation error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating memory properly for the `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`.

Remove `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailedData;` and try putting this inside your `if` block:

```
    // Get the required bufferLength
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet,
                                    &deviceInterfaceData,
                                    nullptr,
                                    0,
                                    &bufferLength,
                                    nullptr);
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get bufferLength.  Error "
                  << GetLastError() << '\n';
        return;
    }

    // Create device interface detailed information struct pointer
    // and allocate memory to it.
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailedData(nullptr);
    deviceInterfaceDetailedData =
        static_cast<PSP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA>(malloc(bufferLength));
    if(deviceInterfaceDetailedData == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to allocate memory.  Error "
                  << GetLastError() << '\n';
        return;
    }
    deviceInterfaceDetailedData->cbSize =
        sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA);

    // Get detailed information
    if(SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet,
                                       &deviceInterfaceData,
                                       deviceInterfaceDetailedData,
                                       bufferLength,
                                       &bufferLength,
                                       nullptr))
    {
        //deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(bufferLength);
        std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    free(deviceInterfaceDetailedData);
```

I haven't looked at the rest of the code, it may have errors too, but this answers your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have entered the SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInterfaceData, nullptr, 0, &bufferLength, nullptr); like you've showed and it didn't even get pass that. It returned a 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) just as stated in the code :(

Comment: Sorry, nvm. your code works :P mistyped something thanks alot :D.

Answer (score 3):

Having found this topic, I'd like to share my problem that using exactly the same source, I got ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER from the call.

The reason was the line:

```
deviceInterfaceDetailedData->cbSize =
        sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA);
```

which on my quadbyte aligned compiler set the value 8 instead of the required value 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is according to MSDN definition:

Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with a NULLDeviceInterfaceDetailData pointer, a DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize of zero, and a valid RequiredSize variable. **In response to such a call, this function returns the required buffer size at RequiredSize and fails with GetLastError returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.**

So, after ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER error just use requiredSize value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I have already done that within the second SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail function. But still no luck with it.